# My website running on an ubuntu server went down after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I was going to add something to my php.ini file so I added it and rebooted the server.  My site went down after the reboot citing that it could not connect to the database so I reversed the changes and rebooted again but nothing changed.

I have been debugging for a while and so I have narrowed it down to the local instance of mysql running on the server has a problem

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-04-17 17:10:27 UTC; 11min ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
    Process: 2154 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2205 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2205 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Error: 13 (Permission denied)
```

then I dug further into the log file for mysql:

```
2023-04-17T16:16:42.385405Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2023-04-17T16:16:42.385446Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-012595] [InnoDB] The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
```

I am using a digitalocean droplet for this site, anyone know which directory or something needs access rights and/or what the command is to fix it?

Comment: Hello. The issue seems to come from some of you files permissions.
May you provide the state of permissions of your php.ini file? with a command like `ls -lhiar php.ini`.

And also your mysql files ones: `ls -lhiar /var/lib/mysql` (or a correct path related to your DB files)